# Что это за комната "Обсуждаем мета–вопросы" и почему в ней пинг-понг?

Tags: поддержка, чат

Захожу в [эту комнату](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22474/) и наблюдаю интересный диалог:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что бы это могло значить?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если в комнате долго ничего не писать, она будет заморожена.

Они просто поддерживают в комнате жизнь, чтоб она не была автоматически заморожена.

А если говорить конкретно про эту комнату, то она была создана когда-то для обсуждения мета вопросов сайта.

Comment: Конкретно эта комната не замерзает :-)

Comment: @Grundy я конечно поздно наверное, но тогда зачем так пинги/понги, раз эта комната и так не замерзает? :)

Comment: @PeterKolosov, в чате же ответил - просто так ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy хах, ладно)

Comment: @Grundy вы разбудили деда.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik я не понял юмор? UPD: понял, хах :)